# Xcode Totally dismiss ViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, viewcontroller

I have a very simple question:
How can I "dismiss" a ViewController completely?
After this I want the ViewController to load like if it had been the first time I load the ViewController.
How could I do this? I already tried setNeedsDisplay() but thats not what I want.

Thanks
Jannes

Comment: If you actually want to dismiss a controller then please show which mechanism you use to present it in the first place. If you just want to reset the controller's state then there are probably better alternatives but it would be helpful to explain what you are actually trying to accomplish and why you think reloading a controller solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is to remove the view (not the view controller) That way, when you enter the main view, it will run viewDidLoad again. I have done something similar in a view controller within a navigation controller. When I click the 'back' button, I wanted to remove the view and force it to load again the next time I enter it. I was able to do that with this code:

```
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove)
    {
        NSLog(@"removing view  %@", v);
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
```